# how to continue to the next in Bluebird's map after a catch?

Tags: bluebird

if I encounter an error in the first request.post, I'd like the code to continue to the next, following code just simply stops, any hints?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));
var URLS = ["http://sample.com/j1", "http://sample.com/j2"]

Promise.map(URLS, function (item) {
    return request.postAsync({url: item}).spread(function (response, body) {
        var items = JSON.parse(body)
        return items
    })
}).then(function (r) {
    console.log(r.length)
}).catch(SyntaxError, function (e) {
    console.log('err', e)
});
```